# std::sort comparator which sees the element's (original) index

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, comparator, std

I would like to `std::partial_sort_copy()` an array, but using a custom comparator function. The thing is, this function uses both the *values* of the array cells being compared and their *indices*.

For the sake of discussion, suppose my comaprison function is something like

```
template <typename T>
bool myCompare(size_t lhs_index, const T& lhs, size_t rhs_index, const T& rhs) {
    T lhs_compound = lhs * (lhs_index % 2 ? -1 : 1);
    T rhs_compound = rhs * (lhs_index % 2 ? -1 : 1);
    return (lhs_compound <= rhs_compound);
}
```

<sub>(I can make it more contrived if you like...)</sub>

At first I thought of using a comparator object which takes `pair<size_t, T>`s - but that won't work, since it means my output will be an array of such pairs, and I don't want that. In fact, I need to **not materialize anything** - so no arrays of pairs, or of indices, or any such thing.

What should I do instead?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  Assume you're sorting a `vector` or `array` only?

Comment: @Chad: I actually want to do something more complex, which is use the index in the array to look up something in another array, but I don't want to first do all the lookups and sort an array of tuples.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal: Here's a comparator for you... or rather, here's the comparison I might want to run, not a comparator object. I can't really use a comparator object with pairs, since I don't to have to materialize the array of pairs.

Comment: Are all the initial elements positive or can some be negative also?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal: Assume some might be negative. It's not the problem I'm trying to solve anyway, just an illustration.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that may help.
It create an array of indexes, then sort this array according to the comparator (with indirection to initial array):

```
template <typename IT, typename Comp>
struct MyCmp
{
    explicit Cmp(const IT it, Comp& comp) : it(it), comp(comp) {}
    bool operator (std::size_t lhs, std::size_t rhs) const
    {
        return comp(lhs, *(it + lhs), rhs, *(it + rhs));
    }
    const IT it;
    Comp comp;
};

template<typename IT, typename IT2, typename Comp>
void mypartialsort(IT begin, IT end, IT2 dbegin, IT2 dend, Comp comp)
{
    std::vector<size_t> indexes;
    for (size_t i = 0, size = end - begin; i != size; ++i) {
        indexes.push_back(i);
    }
    MyCmp<IT, Comp> mycomp(begin, comp);
    const std::size_t min_size = std::min(end - begin, dend - dbegin);
    std::partial_sort(v.begin(), v.begin() + d, v.end(), mycomp);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != min_size; ++i, ++dbegin) {
        *dbegin = *(begin + v[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, with an array of indices this all becomes pretty simple, but I need to avoid materializing such a thing for various reasons.

Comment: Have you look at the implementation of `std::patial_sort` ? You may rewrite it to have `mypartialsort(IT begin, IT end, size_t* dbegin, size_t* dend, Comp comp)` (so output is *sorted* index of input), then convert back to real type `T`).

Comment: If I don't find some clever way to get what I want, yes, I will lift the `partial_sort()` or `partial_copy_sort()` code and adapt i.t

Comment: How can you? Sorting algorithms will quickly mutate the sequence and thus "destroy" your index data. I fear you *have* to copy your initial indices to somewhere, so this answer really is the only option.

Comment: @ltjax: `std::patial_sort_copy` doesn't mutate input, so a modified version may output input indexes, (and with hack, in the same place that the output `T`).

Comment: @Jarod42: My point was just that you need to store the indices *somewhere*. Even if you do not modify the input sequence, you will lose the index information quickly while sorting in the output-array. You'd have to know the rank of each element *before* moving it there.

Comment: @ltjax: You just need to **output** the indexes (sizeof output and not sizeof input as in my solution), And I think it is feasible by rewriting `std::partial_sort_copy`.